# uisearchbar perfomance issue textDidChange

Tags: ios5, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I am working on search functionality in my application, I am having list of items based on predicate i am writing the search operation. Search will be based on each character, While doing this search keyboard is responding very late,

I am doing search functionality in delegate method,

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

Can any one suggest how can i solve this issue.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The UI (here, the keyboard) is always updated on the main thread and it may get laggy, if the search task is slow.
Therefore, you should perform it on a separate thread; e.g. by `performSelectorInBackground`. Then the main thread will have enough resources for the keyboard.

See the [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i) for examples.